# How to denote a FOR...LOOP in mathematics

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to help my son with a fairly basic maths question for school.

> How many squares are on a standard $8\times8$ chess board?

We have solved this one quickly, and then explored a number of different ways to calculate the answer in a number of different languages, all similar to the below:

> $ \text{Size} = 8 $
> $ \text{Squares} = \text{FOR } 1 \text{ TO Size: Squares} = \text{Squares} + \text{Size}^2 $

Is there a way to express this kind of loop as a mathematic equation? We've searched some texts at home and online, and got to this

$N=\sum_{s=1}^n s^2$

but I'm not confident this is correct.

I'm trying to count all of the squares of any size. Where $S = 8$ (the size of a chessboard) $N$ (the number of any size square) $= (8 \times 8)+(7 \times 7)+(6 \times 6)+(5 \times 5)+(4 \times 4)+(3 \times 3)+(2 \times 2)+(1 \times 1) = 204 $.

Comment: Why is `Size²` squared? Are you trying to count all unit squares or all squares of any size? Because I don't think this counts either of those because your result appears to be `Size^3`. Are you trying to count the following? $$
\sum_{i=1}^8\sum_{j=1}^8 1 = \sum_{i=1}^{8} 8 = 8\cdot 8 = 8^2
$$

Comment: I'm trying to count all of the squares of any size.

Where S = 8 (the size of a chessboard)

N (the number of any size square) = (8*8)+(7*7)+(6*6)+(5*5)+(4*4)+(3*3)+(2*2)+(1*1) = 204

Thanks for the super-speedy response @Vepir !

Comment: @user3190686 You should probably add your comment in the question to clarify it.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Well the following pesudocode `[set z=0, then do (FOR i=x TO y) { z = z + a(i) }, then return z.]` would be the summation notation in mathematics:

$$
\left(\sum_{i=x}^y a(i)\right)
$$

Then for your problem, you can substitute: $a(i)=i^2$ and $x=1,y=8$. 

P.S. The [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+i%5E2%2C+i%3D1+to+8) recognizes the "sum" command.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Correct Notation for Loop](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/361434/318073). (but it is an old post with no accepted answers)

Comment: Thanks @vepir that notation is what I am after I think! (I've just done the "lazy checking" approach and popped it into an equation solver and it's given the expected response!)

Comment: @Aniruddha Deb has given another great answer that also works using the sum of squares (that I will now go and read up about!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Recurrence relation is probably your best bet here:
$$n_i = n_{i-1} + n^2$$
This explains it pretty well: here's an expansion of the first few terms:
$$\begin{align}
n_1 &= 1 \\
n_2 &= 1 + 4 = 5 \\
n_3 &= 5 + 9 = 14 \\
... \\
n_8 &= 140 + 64 = 204
\end{align}$$

You can also use this direct formula for the sum of squares:
$$n_i = \frac{i(i+1)(2i+1)}{6}$$
This directly gives you $n_8 = \frac{8 \times 9 \times 17}{6} = 204$

Comment: Thanks @Aniruddha! Your answer, combined with the summation notation in the comments has given me an answer! I'm going to go and read all about the sum of squares now!

Comment: @user3190686 [A000330](https://oeis.org/A000330).